# Blink animation when passing 'from' parameter to animation controller?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

since I want to reuse the animation controller multiple times, I pass in `from:0.0` parameter to the controller's constructor, like you see in the code, but when I want to reuse the same controller, at the first one or two milliseconds controller'value will stock on the old one, and I see a blink of the end statement of the animation, then it starts to work like it should.
I have no idea why I'm getting that blink effect.

```
class AnimatedTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation<Alignment> alignAnimation;

  AnimatedTile(this.value, {this.controller, this.alignAnimation});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _playAnimation();
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller.view,
      child: Tile(value),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Align(
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 0.25, heightFactor: 0.25, child: child),
          alignment: alignAnimation.value,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<Null> _playAnimation() async {
    try {
      await controller.forward(from: 0.0).orCancel;
    } on TickerCanceled {
    }
  }
}
```

### EDIT:

It only happens, when I call the `_playAnimation` method, in async style, otherwise that blink effect is gone.

Comment: Would you put more code for the example? I want to trace your code

Comment: I just pass in a tween with alignment animation, and a normall controller that's all, main code is a bit comlicated, although I can send you by email.

Comment: how do you call AnimatedTile ?